# Error al ejecutar el proyecto asp.core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error al ejecutar el proyecto, por favor alguien me indique que pasa gracias.

Comment: Deberías colocar tu código y el error completo para comprender mejor el problema y no una imagen. Así podría alguien ayudarte.

Comment: Que es **AnePortal.dll** ?. Edita la pregunta e indícalo.

Answer (score 2):

Posibles soluciones:

1. Ve al administrador de tareas, y busca los procesos que tienen el mismo nombre que tu solucion y detenlos.
2. Si eso no funciona ve a la carpeta de bin\Debug y elimina todo su contenido. Si no la deja eliminar reiniciando bastara para que el proceso que bloquea tu exe se detenga y vuelva a intentar borrar el contenido de bin\Debug.
3. Ve al proyecto y consegundo a click a Propiedades, luego ve a la pestaña "Seguridad" y desmarca el campo "Habilitar configuración de seguridad de ClickOnce"